# Disable login for useradd

Tags: linux, shell, debian

I tried to disable login for a user account but got this error in debain:

> useradd: unrecognized option '--disabled-login'

What is the equivalent of this command for useradd? Do I have to pick another shell, if so, which one?

Comment: Why are you using `useradd`? `--diabled-login` is an option for *`adduser`*.

Answer (score 4):

Use `nologin` as the default shell:

```
useradd --shell /usr/sbin/nologin [...]
```

*This path is on rpm based packages, not sure if debian has the same.

Comment: It does, the above syntax is valid. Although `adduser` should be preferred where possible.

Comment: This is a hacky way to do it, best not to use this method.

Answer (score 2):

Pay special attention to the use of `useradd` & `adduser` and which distro you're on. The implementations are often different across distros. I usually use `usermod` or `passwd` instead:

For example, you can just lock the password:

```
$ sudo passwd -l <username>
```

To unlock:

```
$ sudo passwd -u <username>
```

I'd also direct you to these Q&A's that already cover the various methods for "locking" a user's account.

- [Disable user shell for security reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55106/disable-user-shell-for-security-reasons)
- [Two ways to lock a password but only one to unlock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109314/two-ways-to-lock-a-password-but-only-one-to-unlock)
- [Disable a user's login without disabling the account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19333/disable-a-users-login-without-disabling-the-account)
- [what does `adduser --disabled-login` do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96892/what-does-adduser-disabled-login-do/96898#96898)

From `useradd`'s man page:

```
--disabled-login
       Do  not  run passwd to set the password.  The user won't be able
       to use her account until the password is set.
```

Comment: 'cmon this is much more "hacking way" that my one. From man pages: "Note that the account is not fully locked - the user can still log in by other means of authentication such as the ssh public key authentication."

Comment: @stderr - no way. This method or usermod are the prescribed methods. Depends on how much disabling you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If the user already exists, consider using usermod. You have more than 1 way to disable login. One is just to not set a password (* or x or anything invalid in /etc/passwd). The other is to set default shell of a user to /bin/false (some distros define /bin/NoShell, /bin/nologin or something).

```
usermod -s /bin/false -p x <username>
```